# Nodejs, async module function call

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

```
var output = "";
//Make article Record.

async.parallel([function (callback) {
    Article.save(Article, function (err, member) {
        //console.log("member : " + member);
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            output = 1;
        } else {
            console.log("Create article record success");
            output = 2;
        }
        callback();
    });
}], function (err, result) {
    console.log("log 1 : " + output);
    res.send(output);
    console.log("log 2 : " + output);
});
```

Hi, I'm in trouble with async lib.

I can get

log 1 : 2

log 2 : 2 from last 2 console.log.

but `res.send(output)` isn't fired. When I replace it with `res.send("2")`, It works.

However, `res.send(output)` doesn't work and my android App generate `SocketTimeoutException` because response isn't sent.

What's the problem? help me.

Comment: Why do you need async.parallel for this? What task do you want to accomplish?

Comment: zaynetro - I intended that output value of res.send function is value after save function works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is simply because you are trying to send a number, which `res.send` will pick up as a status code (and which is invalid). Try changing the following code:

`output = 1;` to `output = "1";` and the same for `output = 2;` to `output = "2";`.

Please see the documentation regarding [`res.send`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.send) and see that a number is not supported:

> `res.send([body])` The body parameter can be a Buffer object, a String, an object, or an Array.

Obviously the `async.parallel` is completely irrelevant in this context, but I'm just going to assume that you really want this instead of making this a design decision.

Answer (score 0):

For this task you don't need `async.parallel` (executes functions in parallel and after last one finished execiting calls callback).

Refer to [async documentation](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel)

```
Article.save(Article, function (err, member) {
  //console.log("member : " + member);
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.send(err);
  }

  console.log("Create article record success");
  res.send("Create article record success");
});
```

You don't need also global variable `output`.